# Can I import data from csv to custom object in salesforce using an Apex method

Tags: apex

I established a connection with a csv file exposed by a Flask API in my laptop to an Apex class. The Apex class sends a web request to the Flask API. Now I want to import the data from csv into a custom object in Salesforce with the another method inside the same Apex class.

Comment: The answer to "Is (thing X) possible in Salesforce?" is usually "yes, if you know enough and/or throw enough time and money into making it work". That said, you'll find this site to be a lot more helpful if you show us the research you've done, the attempt you've made, and narrow things down as much as possible.

Comment: My first reaction to this was "Yes, you could, but it would be easier if you got your data as JSON" (Apex has `JSON.deserialize()` and `JSON.serialize()`, which is a whole lot easier than trying to parse a CSV and dealing with double quote shenanigans). My second reaction was "If you have a CSV, just use [Salesforce's Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/data-loader). Don't try to re-invent the wheel and whatnot".

Comment: If neither of those approaches (use JSON, use Dataloader) are appropriate for your scenario, then the onus is on you to explain why. Sites like this _thrive_ on detail; so the more detailed you can be, the better. It's also very helpful to give us information about your overall goal so you avoid [the XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Yes, Derek F I recently discovered, just before reading your message, that JSON is a better hack. I will abandon CSV method...No I don't want to use data loader or data import wizard. The main goal of my project is to create an automated process of loading data into a custom object  with custom fields in Salesforce. The data is created by Python functions and I expose it to Salesforce with Flask. I might share code of my progress here in terms of code for your input. Thanks

Comment: Ah, with that little bit of additional information, there's probably a better path forward here. Look into using "Simple Salesforce" in python to do your record creation ([link to some relevant documentation](https://simple-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/record_management.html)).